# ForEach inside of ForEach?

Tags: powershell

What I'm trying to do is loop through $uriProcess for $ProjectProcessConfiguration and $FieldControlConfiguration for each workitem type and page.

```
$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$(PAT)")) }

$projectProcessConfiguration= @{ 
 "controlls"= "null"                        
  "id"= "null"
  "label"= "Company"
  "order"= "0"
  "overridden"= "null"
  "inherited"= "null"
  "visible"= "true"
}  | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

$FieldControlConfiguration = @{ 
  "id"= "Custom.ID"
  "label"= "ID"
  "controlType"= "FieldControl"
  "readOnly"= "true"
  "visible"= "true"
  "isContribution"= "false"
}  | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

$uriProcess= "https://dev.azure.com/$(Company)/_apis/work/processes/$(CMMI)/workItemTypes/CMMIinherited.Bug/layout/pages/CMMI.Bug.Bug/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uriProcess -Method POST -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -Body $projectProcessConfiguration -ContentType "application/json"
```

So each of these would be used to make a total of 9 URL's:

```
$Pages= "CMMI.Bug.Bug","CMMI.ChangeRequest.ChangeRequest","CMMI.Epic.Epic","CMMI.Feature.Feature","CMMI.Issue.Issue","CMMI.Requirement.Requirement","CMMI.Review.Review","CMMI.Risk.Risk","CMMI.Task.Task"

$WorkItems="CMMIinherited.Bug","CMMIinherited.ChangeRequest","CMMIinherited.Epic","CMMIinherited.Feature","CMMIinherited.Issue","CMMIinherited.Requirement","CMMIinherited.Review","CMMIinherited.Risk","CMMIinherited.Task"
```

Sending just one of these would look like this:

```
$uriProcess= "https://dev.azure.com/$(Company)/_apis/work/processes/$(CMMI)/workItemTypes/CMMIinherited.Bug/layout/pages/CMMI.Bug.Bug/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
```

Next one would look like this:

```
$uriProcess= "https://dev.azure.com/$(Company)/_apis/work/processes/$(CMMI)/workItemTypes/CMMIinherited.ChangeRequest/layout/pages/CMMI.ChangeRequest.ChangeRequest/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
```

Hopefully that makes sense.

I want to create 9 URL's each with there own special values and send each one over Invoke-Restmethod

I was thinking a foreach loop but my "$pages" and "$workItems" don't seem to line up in a foreach so I'm getting bad results. It sounds like this is not a good way to do this anyways. Any advice on how this could be done in a simple layout?

Comment: Please show us more of the not correct output and the output you would expect. Also, if you have error messages, add these in full to the question. As it is now, there are too many variables unexplained ($Org, $CMMI, $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader, $projectProcessConfiguration). Are you sure these are all defined and correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Write-Host, if you plan to use the data elsewhere.

Write-host is not needed to send output to the screen, that is the PowerShell default. If you absolutely 'want' to use a write, for whatever your reasons, then choose Write-Output instead.

You can assign to a variable and output to the screen at the same time using variable squeezing. Yet, only really do this for dev / debug sessions or if you really plan to have this output to the screen all the time.

Show the results you are expecting, vs forcing folks to assume or guess. What errors are occurring? When I do this, with your sample, the results happen with no errors, though a few oddball formats are there.

```
# Simple string only needs single quotes. Double is for expansion needs and specific formatting 
$Org       = 'MyOrgName'
$CMMI      = 'MyCMMIThingy'
$Pages     = 'C.Bug','C.Change','C.Epic'
$WorkItems = 'Bug','Change','Epic'

ForEach ($WorkItemTypes in $WorkItems) # This will happen 3 times
{
    # Assign the results to the variable for later use, while outputting to the screen
    '*'*60
    "*** Processing worktypes named $WorkItemTypes ***"
    '*'*60
    ($uriProcess2 = "https://dev.azure.com/$Org/_apis/work/processes/$CMMI/workItemTypes/$WorkItemTypes/layout/pages/")

    ForEach ($PageTypes in $Pages) # This will happen 3 times for each of $WorkItems
    {
        # Assign the results to the variable for later use, while outputting to the screen
        '*'*60
        "*** Processing page types name $PageTypes  for worktypes named $WorkItemTypes for the Invoke command ***"
        '*'*60
        ($uriProcess3 = "$PageTypes/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1")
        <#
        Assign the results to the variable for later use, while outputting to the screen
        Using splatting for readability
        #>
        ($uriProcess = $uriProcess2 + $uriProcess3)
        <#
        $invokeRestMethodSplat = @{
            ContentType = 'application/json'
            Method = 'POST'
            Body = $projectProcessConfiguration
            Headers = $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader
            Uri = $uriProcess
        }
        Invoke-RestMethod @invokeRestMethodSplat
        #>
    }
}

<#
# Results


************************************************************
*** Processing worktypes named Bug ***
************************************************************
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/_apis/work/processes/MyCMMIThingy/workItemTypes/Bug/layout/pages/
************************************************************
*** Processing page types name C.Bug  for worktypes named Bug for the Invoke command ***
************************************************************
C.Bug/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/_apis/work/processes/MyCMMIThingy/workItemTypes/Bug/layout/pages/C.Bug/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1   
************************************************************
*** Processing page types name C.Change  for worktypes named Bug for the Invoke command ***
************************************************************
C.Change/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/_apis/work/processes/MyCMMIThingy/workItemTypes/Bug/layout/pages/C.Change/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1************************************************************
*** Processing page types name C.Epic  for worktypes named Bug for the Invoke command ***
************************************************************
C.Epic/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/_apis/work/processes/MyCMMIThingy/workItemTypes/Bug/layout/pages/C.Epic/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1  
************************************************************
*** Processing worktypes named Change ***
************************************************************
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/_apis/work/processes/MyCMMIThingy/workItemTypes/Change/layout/pages/
************************************************************
*** Processing page types name C.Bug  for worktypes named Change for the Invoke command ***
************************************************************
C.Bug/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/_apis/work/processes/MyCMMIThingy/workItemTypes/Change/layout/pages/C.Bug/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1************************************************************
*** Processing page types name C.Change  for worktypes named Change for the Invoke command ***
************************************************************
C.Change/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/_apis/work/processes/MyCMMIThingy/workItemTypes/Change/layout/pages/C.Change/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1
************************************************************
*** Processing page types name C.Epic  for worktypes named Change for the Invoke command ***
************************************************************
C.Epic/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/_apis/work/processes/MyCMMIThingy/workItemTypes/Change/layout/pages/C.Epic/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1
************************************************************
*** Processing worktypes named Epic ***
************************************************************
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/_apis/work/processes/MyCMMIThingy/workItemTypes/Epic/layout/pages/
************************************************************
*** Processing page types name C.Bug  for worktypes named Epic for the Invoke command ***
************************************************************
C.Bug/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/_apis/work/processes/MyCMMIThingy/workItemTypes/Epic/layout/pages/C.Bug/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1
************************************************************
*** Processing page types name C.Change  for worktypes named Epic for the Invoke command ***
************************************************************
C.Change/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/_apis/work/processes/MyCMMIThingy/workItemTypes/Epic/layout/pages/C.Change/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1
************************************************************
*** Processing page types name C.Epic  for worktypes named Epic for the Invoke command ***
************************************************************
C.Epic/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/_apis/work/processes/MyCMMIThingy/workItemTypes/Epic/layout/pages/C.Epic/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1
#>
```

You are getting the 3 items for each because that is what you are asking it to do via the nested loop.

Whenever you are working to debug iteration/loops, always go to the smallest amount of code possible to make sure you are getting the base results you are after...

```
$Pages     = 'C.Bug','C.Change','C.Epic'
$WorkItems = 'Bug','Change','Epic'

ForEach ($WorkItemTypes in $WorkItems)
{
    " Work type is `"$WorkItemTypes`""       
    ForEach ($PageTypes in $Pages)
    {"Page type is $PageTypes and work type is `"$WorkItemTypes`""}
}

<#
# Results

 Work type is "Bug"
Page type is C.Bug and work type is "Bug"
Page type is C.Change and work type is "Bug"
Page type is C.Epic and work type is "Bug"
 Work type is "Change"
Page type is C.Bug and work type is "Change"
Page type is C.Change and work type is "Change"
Page type is C.Epic and work type is "Change"
 Work type is "Epic"
Page type is C.Bug and work type is "Epic"
Page type is C.Change and work type is "Epic"
Page type is C.Epic and work type is "Epic"
#>
```

***Update***

As per my comment to you, take that action because as written in your comment, I have no idea what this is to be...

> Ultimately I'm looking to get this as the output: Work type is "Bug"
>   Page type is C.Bug and work type is "Bug" Work type is "Change" Page
>   type is C.Change and work type is "Change" Work type is "Epic" Page
>   type is C.Epic and work type is "Epic"

... or really means for you use-case end results. However, a loop would never process this way, with what and the way you've provided it.

Even breaking that into segments, has me scratching my head right now.

```
Work type is "Bug" Page type is C.Bug 
and 
work type is "Bug" 
Work type is "Change" Page type is C.Change 
and 
work type is "Change" 
Work type is "Epic" Page type is C.Epic 
and 
work type is "Epic"
```

You are iterating over a list, it's only going process each item once. If I did part of what you have here as a loop using a multi-dimensional array, you can do this.

```
Clear-Host
$Org       = 'MyOrgName'
$CMMI      = 'MyCMMIThingy'
$Counter   = -1
# Using multi-dimentional arrays
$WorkItems = @('Bug','Change','Epic'),@('C.Bug','C.Change','C.Epic')
$WorkItems[0] | 
ForEach{
    $Counter++
    ($uriProcess2 = "https://dev.azure.com/$Org/_apis/work/processes/$CMMI/workItemTypes/$($WorkItems[0][$Counter])/layout/pages/$($WorkItems[1][$Counter])")

}

<#
# Results

https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/_apis/work/processes/MyCMMIThingy/workItemTypes/Bug/layout/pages/C.Bug
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/_apis/work/processes/MyCMMIThingy/workItemTypes/Change/layout/pages/C.Change
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/_apis/work/processes/MyCMMIThingy/workItemTypes/Epic/layout/pages/C.Epic
#>
```

Comment: Wow I really need to read up on this topic more. I appreciate the help. Ultimately I'm looking to get this as the output:
 Work type is "Bug"
Page type is C.Bug and work type is "Bug"
 Work type is "Change"
Page type is C.Change and work type is "Change"
 Work type is "Epic"
Page type is C.Epic and work type is "Epic"
#>

Comment: No worries, we all go thru such stages. Also, rather than put what you did in the comment section, meaning, that code/result block, update your question, with exactly what the end expectation is,  so that it can be more directly followed by folks who may come upon it later. If you are only expecting 3 responses, then, yep, it needs to be re-thought, as this approach you are using now is specifically asking for 9 responses as shown.

Comment: I knew I was over complicating this. The ulti-dimensional array seems to be on track with what I'm trying to do!

Comment: Good to know it sounds like an option for you. Good luck and take care.

Comment: Thanks! I have a long way to go with learning. How could I make this into a multi-dimensional array with 3 values vs 2?

Comment: What do you mean? IN the MDA shown, there are already 3 values in both arrays. You can have as many elements in either array as you choose, you just need to know the impact of the decision, in a use case. Just do quick search on the web, Youtube, MSDN channel9, MS Techcommunity using ---  'powershell multi-dimentional arrays' for all the down and gory details.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $Pages= "C.Bug","C.Change","C.Epic"
    $WorkItems= "Bug","Change","Epic"

    ForEach ($WorkItemTypes in $WorkItems)
    {
        $uriProcess2= "https://dev.azure.com/`$Org/_apis/work/processes/`$CMMI/workItemTypes/$WorkItemTypes/layout/pages/"
        Write-Host $uriProcess2    
        ForEach ($PageTypes in $Pages)        {
            $uriProcess3= "$PageTypes/sections/Section3/groups?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
            Write-Host $uriProcess3
            $uriProcess= $uriProcess2 + $uriProcess3
            Write-Host $uriProcess 
            Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uriProcess -Method POST -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -Body $projectProcessConfiguration -ContentType "application/json"
        }
    }
```

Comment: hmm I'm still running into an issue. It seems to be looping way too many times. I'm getting a mix of errors and some correct output. IT looks like my page variable isn't lining up with my workitems in some cases.